# VBA creates @ sign on Formula

Tags: excel, vba

When I run my VBA macro the following code creates the formula as shown in the second with 3 "@" signs on it and the formula doesn't work unless the "@" signs are manually deleted. This is violating my macros completency. I would be glad if you could help.

```
 Range("L2:L" & Lastrow2).Formula = _
    "=IFERROR(INDEX(İade!R2C10:R5000C10,SMALL(IF(RC[-11]=İade!R2C1:R5000C1,ROW(İade!R2C10:R5000C10)-1,""""), RC[-10])),"""")"
```

```
=IFERROR(@INDEX(İade!$C$2:$C$5000;SMALL(IF(A2=@İade!$A$2:$A$5000;@ROW(İade!$C$2:$C$5000)-1;""); B2));"")
```

Comment: Try enclosing the sheet name `Iade` in single quotation marks, like 'Iade'. If that doesn't help, try replacing that name with one that features only letters from the English alphabet.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of them worked.

Comment: If you want to assign an R1C1 formula then use `.FormulaR1C1` not `.Formula`

Comment: It didn't help with the issue.

Comment: Non standard characters like `İ` can cause issues. Try to rename it to somthing using standard (english) characters only and try again. • After that at least we know if that non-standard character is the issue or not.

Comment: Try using Formula2 rather than Formula - that should create a formula without the @

Comment: @CharlesWilliams - what's with the `@` ?  Is that a known issue?  Difficult to Google for...

Comment: The @ sign is used in Office 365 Excel versions that support dynamic arrays to make the expression use implicit intersection. For compatibility reasons VBA .Formula generates formulas as though they were created in XL 2013 - hence the @ because in XL 2013 that formula would have used implicit intersection. in DA Excel .Formula 2 generates dynamic array style formulas. For more info see my CHECKDA blog post at https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2019/05/20/compatibility-of-office-365-dynamic-array-formulas/